# Is there a way to generate the documentation of a buildConfigField in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, buildconfig

I have in my gradle various `buildConfigField`s and I would like to generate the JavaDoc for one of those in the `BuildConfig` class.
I already have a comment in gradle

```
buildConfigField 'Integer', 'BACKGROUND_COUNTDOWN', '30 * 60 * 1000 - 10000' // 29 minutes, 50 seconds, the remaining 10 seconds are countdown shown in the foreground
```

I would like to have that comment written in JavaDoc above the corresponding constant in `BuildConfig`

```
/**
* 29 minutes, 50 seconds, the remaining 10 seconds are countdown shown in the foreground
*/
public static final Integer STOP_ALARM_BACKGROUND_COUNTDOWN = 30 * 60 * 1000 - 10000;
```

this way, when another programmer does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> on that constant, whenever they find it in the code, they see the comment as documentation, without having to go look it up in the gradle file.

[image]

Is such a thing even possible?

Answer (score 0):

[As per the official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.2/com/android/build/api/variant/BuildConfigField) there seems to have a field called `comment`. It doesn't specify if it's a `//`-style comment or a `javadoc`-style comment; you might give that a try

Comment: how am I supposed to use that `comment`? I've tried `buildConfigField 'Integer', 'BACKGROUND_COUNTDOWN', '30 * 60 * 1000 - 10000', '"bananana"'` but it gives `Could not find method BuildConfigField() for arguments [Integer, BACKGROUND_COUNTDOWN, 30 * 60 * 1000 - 10000, "bananana"]`

Comment: I've made tens of attempts at including that `comment` in my gradle but not a single one worked

Comment: You'd need to use the available public constructor and pass the third argument with something meaningful [as these guys are doing in reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/pf5ze2/buildgradle_adding_buildconfig_field_dynamically/)